# Power Series Representation at a given value a

Tags: calculus

Find a power series representation for the function centered at a given value of *a* and determine the radius of convergence.

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^3};  a=0 $$

How would i begin with this type of question?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the fact that this can be found by differentiating the result from a geometric series:

$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{1 - x} = \sum_0^\infty x^i \\
g'(x) = \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2} \\
g''(x) = \frac{2}{(1 - x)^3}
$$

So if you start with $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1 - x}$, then $f(x) = g''(x)$.

**edit**

You just need to differentiate the original power series (note that you lose the first, constant, term each time you differentiate):

$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1 - x} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_0^\infty x^i \\
g'(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_1^\infty ix^{i - 1} \\
g''(x) = f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_2^\infty i(i - 1)x^{i - 2}
$$

If you want to re-index, then you simply do the following:

$$
i' = i - 2 \rightarrow i = i' + 2 \\
f(x) = g''(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_0^\infty (i + 1)(i + 2)x^i
$$

If you write out the first few terms, you get:

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(2 + 6x + 12x^2 + 20x^3 + 30x^4 + ...\right)
$$

Which you can verify with [Newton's Generalised Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem):

$$
\frac{1}{(1 - x)^s} = \sum_0^\infty \binom{s + k - 1}{k}x^k
$$

We have $s = 3$, so this gives:

$$
\binom{3 + 0 - 1}{0} = \binom{2}{0} = 1 \\
\binom{3 + 1 - 1}{1} = \binom{3}{1} = 3 \\
\binom{3 + 2 - 1}{2} = \binom{4}{2} = 6 
$$

You can see that this is the same as what we got above (don't forget the divide by 2).

Comment: What would you do after you found that f(x)=g″(x)?

Comment: sorry but how would we find the radius of convergence?

Comment: The radius of convergence is obviously 1 because that's the radius of convergence of the original power series: $\sum x^i$.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot!

Comment: oh one last thing, what does it mean when it says at a=0?

Comment: In general a power series looks like this: $\sum a_i(x - x_0)^i$, by "$a = 0$", it means $x_0 = 0$, i.e. $\sum a_i (x - 0)^i = \sum a_ix^i$.  If it had been centered about any other value (other than $0$), this would have been a much more difficult problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** To find the power series you can use the [generalized binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).