# Represent Power Series of a function

Tags: power-series

Hi could anyone help me answer this question

Find the power series representation for the function and determine the radius of convergence

$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{\left(1-2x\right)^2}$

After getting 1/(1-2x)^2 I do not know how to convert it to a power series.

Comment: Can you do it if the $x^2$ wasn't there?  If so just drop it out, then once you have the power series for $\frac{1}{(1 - 2x)^2}$, just multiply the whole thing by $x^2$ (i.e. just add $2$ to each $x$-term's exponent).

Comment: How do I then represent 1/(1-2x)^2 as a power series?

Comment: Can you integrate $\frac{1}{(1 - 2x)^2}$?  See what that gives you.

Comment: Here is a very similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728299/power-series-representation-at-a-given-value-a/728307#728307

Comment: That gave me (1/2)(1/(1-2X))

Comment: $\frac{1}{1 - 2x}$ should look very familiar.

Comment: Oh thanks so that would be summation of (2x)^r

Comment: yes, that is correct.  First, think about how you can get back to $\frac{1}{(1 - 2x)^2}$ and second, _don't_ forget about that $\frac{1}{2}$!

Comment: oh and don't forget about the $x^2$ at the end either!

Comment: And btw, you can use inline latex by surrounding it with `$`'s.  You already are using basic latex syntax, for instance x^2, just place in inside `$`'s: `$x^2$` = $x^2$.  For fractions you use `\frac{}{}` where the first braces is the numerator and the second the denominator, for instance `$\frac{x^2}{(1 - 2x)^2}$` = $\frac{x^2}{(1 - 2x)^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Some starting material:** 
Using that $\sum_{n=0} ^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$, we can write 
$$
f(x) = \frac{x^2}{1 - 4x + 4x^2} = x^2 \cdot \frac{1}{1 - (4x - 4x^2)} = x^2 \sum_{n=0} ^\infty 4^n x^n(1-x)^n = \sum_{n=0} ^\infty 4^n x^{n+2}(1-x)^n.
$$
I imagine you can take it from here.

Comment: it looks a bit delicate to me to get to the result from your start...

Comment: @mookid At first I was not sure what you meant - then I realized that this was supposed to be a power series! No idea what I was thinking. Good point, I guess my answer turned out to be not particularly helpful.

Comment: you can always expand the sum and swap both sums, but you then have a tricky sum to compute exactly. It may not be the end of the world...

Comment: Hmm.... I started along that route. I am sure it is possible, however, I am not seeing it.. I reduced it all the way, but I don't see how to move it beyond this: $$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0} ^\infty \sum_{k=0} ^n \binom{n}{k} 4^n (-1)^k x^{k + n + 2}  .$$ I think that for now I will accede that my answer was a little rash..

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$
|z|<1\implies \frac {1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n;\\
\frac d{dx}\frac {1}{1-x} = \frac {1}{(1-x)^2};
|x|<1\implies \frac {1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n.\\
$$
Now make the substitution $x\to 2x$:
$$|x|<\frac 12\implies \frac {1}{(1-2x)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)2^nx^n\\
\implies \frac {x^2}{(1-2x)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)2^nx^{n+2}.
$$

Then you see that for $x=1/2$, $(n+1)2^nx^{n+2}\nrightarrow 0$: the radius is $1/2$.